# Windows7: Reactivate sound after crash

Tags: windows-7, audio, crash

It happens that sounds stop working, often after the laptop has been hibernated.

- Which are the services responsible for audio in Windows 7?
- Is it possible to reactivate audio after a crash without rebooting
  the machine?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to press Windows+R type devmgmt.msc, unfold "sound, video and game devices" (sorry i don't have english windows) and turn off sound card then turn it on again. Works on all my soundblaster cards.